# Spring Boot: Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend - saveAndFlush(S)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I just started a Spring Boot course which uses an older version (2.19) while I use 3.0.2. Here is a representative part of the code first:

My custom repository:

```
public interface SessionRepository extends JpaRepository<Session,Long> {

}
```

The endpoint in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public Session update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Session session){
        //in original version used in the course use findOne(Id) (deprecated)
        Optional<Session> existingSession = sessionRepository.findById(id);
        //take existing session and copy incoming session data onto it
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(session, existingSession, "session_id");
        return sessionRepository.saveAndFlush(existingSession);
    }
```

All is fine until saveAndFlush, which gives me the above mentioned error.

It appears with the latest Spring Boot 3.0.2 findOne() has been deprecated and instead I have to use findById() and return an Optional type. Several questions on this type of error have been answered referring to findOne(id) method, however, this isn't the source of my problem and I can't figure out how to fix my code..

About the methods I'm using:

saveAndFlush in JpaRepository:

```
<S extends T> S saveAndFlush(S entity);
```

and findById in CrudRepository:

```
Optional<T> findById(ID id);
```

I understand the problem is that in my case both S and T are the same Session object - hence the error is telling me to extend the Session model.
Session is T, the object in my custom repository (SessionRepository), but it is also S, the object I pass in and return from saveAndFlush(). Instead, I should be passing and returning something that is extended from my Session object (S extends T0. I am not sure how to extend this without breaking everything else in my code, I feel instead I should overwrite something, as other have suggested, but I am not sure where to do that

Comment: What do you want to do when there is no session with the given `id`?

Comment: An `Optional<Session>` isn't a session. The problem is you are trying to copy the properties to an `Optional<Session>` (which won't do anything) and then try to store the `Optional<Session>`, which as mentioned and as the error is telling you isn't a `Session`. Hence it fails. You need to unwrap the object (if it exists from the optional).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your code. The `findById` as you mention yourself and from the documentation returns an `Optional<Session>`. This is a `Session` wrapped in an `Optional` and thus it isn't a `Session`.

The `saveAndFlush` (like `save`) requires a `Session` which, the wrapped `Session` clearly isn't. What you need to do is unwrap the `Session` from the `Optional` (if it actually exists).

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public Session update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Session session){
    return sessionRepository.findById(id)
        .map(existingSession -> updateSession(existingSession, session))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No session for id '" + ids + "'");
}

private Session updateSession(Session existingSession, Session session) {
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(session, existingSession, "session_id");
    return sessionRepository.saveAndFlush(existingSession);
}
```

Comment: No I didn't, else I would have used `map`. Which is what you could use if you are on JDK8, for JDK9 or up you could use the `ifPresentOrElse` or still use `map`.

Comment: Blame it on mondays, too little coffee and writing that from the top of my head.